# How to read data from database with json PHP JQUERY Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Im trying to read data from mysql database and pass it to my javascript file.
I have search alot on internet and have found examples that doesnt work in my case.

.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Display Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<button type='button' id='getdata'>Get Data.</button>

<div id='result_table'>

</div>

<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#getdata').click(function(){
    alert("hello");
    $.ajax({
            url: 'db.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_string){
                    alert(output_string);
                },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                    }
    }); 

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and .php file

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '123';
        $host = 'localhost';
        $db = 'internetProgrammeringProj';

        $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        $select = mysql_select_db($db,$connect);

        $query = $_POST['query'];
        $mysql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratt ");
        $temp = "";
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fletch_assoc($mysql_query)){
            $temp = $row['id'];
            $temp .= $row['namn'];
            $temp .= $row['typ'];
            $temp .= $row['url'];
            $temp .= $row['forberedelse'];

            $array[i] = $temp; 
            $i++;
        }



        echo json_encode($array);   
?>
```

alert(xhr.statusText); gives parsererror

and

alert(thrownError); gives  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

firebug doesnt display any error in console.

**QUESTION**: How do i get my program to get the content from the database and pass it with json to display it with alert in ajax?

Comment: The `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character` suggests that jQuery failed to parse the response text as JSON because it's *not* valid JSON. Use Firebug to see what response text is being returned and post that here as well.

Comment: check your array use vat_dump to get it

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully ran this code.

All I had to do is remove the `echo "hello"` at the beginning which messes up your JSON.

Some more tips you can use for future development:

- Don't use `alert('message')`. Use `console.log('message')`. You can view the output of `console.log` in "Developer's Area". In chrome you simply press F12. I think that in FF you need to install firebug or something.
- `output_string` in function `success` is actually an object.
- The "Developer's Area" in chrome also lets you see the response from backend. If you have used it you could have seen your output is `hello{ "key":"value"}` and immediately notice the nasty hello in the beginning. Read more about it at http://wiki.mograbi.info/developers-tools-for-web-development